# How to use 2 IPs on one Apache server

Tags: networking, debian, apache2

I have two IPs (and domains) on my dedicated Linux server (Debian). I'm able to access the primary domain. But when I try to access the 2nd one, I'm directed to the primary site.

In `/etc/network/interfaces`, I have this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.99.233.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.99.233.0
    broadcast 192.99.233.255
    gateway 192.99.233.254

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 149.56.155.72
    netmask 255.255.255.255

post-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 149.56.155.72 netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast 149.56.155.72
pre-down /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 down
```

I restarted the network: `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Then I made two new `.conf` files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, one for each domain.

site1.conf: **Updated**

```
<VirtualHost 192.99.233.101:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    Servername site1.net
    ServerAlias www.site1.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

site2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 149.56.155.72:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site2.co
    ServerName site2.co
    ServerAlias www.site2.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I ran these three cmds:

```
`a2dissite 000-default.conf`
`a2ensite site1.conf`
`a2ensite site2.conf`
```

and lastly, I restarted apache. And I keep getting site1 each time i try to pull up site2. I've done the rdns for site2 and everything there is right.

This is my first attempt to do something like this. Can someone see what I'm not doing...or what more needs to be done? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

```
root@dfwit:~# apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using site2.co. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  site2.co (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server site2.co (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost site2.co (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.conf:1)
             alias www.site2.co
     port 80 namevhost site1.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:1)
             alias www.site1.net
root@dfwit:~#
```

Does this look right?

**Another UPDATE**

```
root@dfwit:~# getent hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
192.99.233.101  xtremeirc.net xtremeirc.net
149.56.155.72   dfwit.co dfwit.co
127.0.0.1       ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
root@dfwit:~#
```

And here are `ping` results:

```
root@dfwit:~# ping xtremeirc.net
PING xtremeirc.net (192.99.233.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from xtremeirc.net (192.99.233.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms

root@dfwit:~# ping dfwit.co
PING dfwit.co (149.56.155.72) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dfwit.co (149.56.155.72): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
```

So the DNS appears to be resolving correctly. But site1 still loads for site2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need matching DNS entries.  It appears both sites may be resolving to the same IP.  The first VHOST defined on each IP address will be the default site, and handle any sites that don't resolve.

If you want to use IP based domains, you need to match your DNS configuration.  Check the results of `host` and/or `getent hosts` to see what your DNS configuration is.

If you are using IP addresses as you show, I would expect each IP combination to show up as a separate NameVirtualHost entry.  Prior to Apache 2.4 there was a NameVirtualHost directive that could be used to specify VirtualHost IP/Port combinations.  If you are using Apache 2.2, try adding matching NameVirtualHost directives before the VirtualHost specifications.  You may need to remove the existing NameVirtualHost *:80 directive.

You can use the access log for debugging.  Adding the local address (`%A`) to the log along with the site and port (`%v:%p`) will allow you to ensure traffic is flowing on the the correct IP addresses. For a CGI script `SERVER_ADDR` contains the local IP for the connection.

Comment: Please see the last update. I also added site2 and its IP to `/etc/hosts`. Please advise.

Comment: @Landslyde I've updated my response with details on NaveVirtualHost.  Further details on the Apache documentation site.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.4.10. This is so frustrating. I know this can be done, and I've followed all the instructions provided to me. And my post displays everything I've done. I just don't get it.

Comment: @Landslyde Try getting the sites working on *:80 and *:443.  Once you have that working, put up a page that displays the local address on both.  That may help debug your issues. You can also use a custom log format  to debug networking.

Comment: That was it, BillThor. Thank you so much. I hadn't made changes to the `default-ssl.conf`. That's why it kept on pulling up site1: it was set to the wrong directory. Feeling kind of stupid now, but I do appreciate your guidance. Have a great day, sir.

Comment: BillThor: if I type in the domain name `www.dfwit.co`, I get an error page with `The requested URL /defaultsite was not found on this server.` But if I type in `www.dfwit.co/index.php`, I get to my site. Any ideas?

Comment: @Landslyde  May be an incorrect index setting possibly in .htaccess.  The error log may have some information as well.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I got it working. I tried to be fully explanatory on this, showed my work, and someone still down votes me. Funny how some people are like that. Anyway, have a great day, BillThor. And thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should set a `ServerName` for each vhost, and `ServerAlias` as needed.  You also, probably don't need to be explicitly targeting a IP in your vhost configs.  Just try doing `<VirtualHost *:80>` for both.

Past that, look at the output of `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` it will tell you if your vhosts are actually configured the way you think they are.

Comment: I made those changes. Now when I type in site2, I get a 404 file. But if I type in site2/index.php, I get site1. Here are my domains: site1 = `www.xtremeirc.net` and site2 = `www.dfwit.co`. Could you verify what I'm getting?

Comment: And as a side note, the secure certificate is working for site2, even though it's pulling up site1. So at least that's working :-)